# シェル内のコメント用記号`<# #>`を文字列として扱いたい

Tags: zsh, shell

シェルスクリプトでソースコード内にある`<#CLIENT_KEY#>`という文字列を`12345789` に置き換えたいのですが、エラーになってしまって実行できません。

```
./ci_post_clone.sh:13: parse error near `\n'
```

おそらく`<# #>`がコメント形式のためエラーになってしまっているのですが、どのように対処すればよいでしょうか？

```bash
#!/bin/zsh

#  ci_post_clone.sh

env_file_path="./Source.c"

typeset -A envValues

CLIENT_KEY=12345789
CLIENT_SECRET_KEY=987654321

envValues[<#CLIENT_KEY#>]=$CLIENT_KEY
envValues[<#CLIENT_SECRET_KEY#>]=$CLIENT_SECRET_KEY

for key in ${(k)envValues}
  sed -i -e "s/${key}/${envValues[$key]}/g" "${env_file_path}"
```

Comment: 何かしらやりようはあるのかもしれませんが、「ソースコード中の記述を変更する(`#` を削除する)」のは難しいのでしょうか？

Comment: できればソースコード内の<##>という形を利用したいので、可能であれば両立させたいです。

Comment: バックスラッシュでエスケープしてみては？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

既に解決済みですが、`sed` コマンドの `-f` オプションを使う方法もあります。

```bash
#!/bin/sh

env_file_path='./Source.c'

cat <<EOT | sed -i -E -f- "${env_file_path}"
s/<#CLIENT_KEY#>/12345789/g
s/<#CLIENT_SECRET_KEY#>/987654321/g
EOT
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。今回のケースだと一度変数に入れるような形だと同じような値を変数に入れてしまっているので、こちらの方法でやってみたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

置換後の文字列をいったん変数に代入して、その変数を参照するようにすればうまくいくと思います。
代入するときは`'`でクォートする必要があります。

```
#!/bin/zsh
#  ci_post_clone.sh
env_file_path="./Source.c"
typeset -A envValues
CLIENT_KEY=12345789
CLIENT_SECRET_KEY=987654321
r1='<#CLIENT_KEY#>'
r2='<#CLIENT_SECRET_KEY#>'
envValues[$r1]=$CLIENT_KEY
envValues[$r2]=$CLIENT_SECRET_KEY

for key in ${(k)envValues}
  sed -i -e "s/${key}/${envValues[$key]}/g" "${env_file_path}"
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。うまくいきました。